# ERROR : javax.servlet does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, servlets

I have checked almost all the posts possible for the error that I'm getting. Ive edited almost all the **ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES** as given online. These are my environment variables :

**ANT_HOME** = C:\Ant9;C:\Tomcat7\lib\servlet-api.jar

**CLASSPATH** = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Tomcat7\lib\servlet-api.jar;.

**JAVA_HOME** = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24

**PATH** = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin

**TOMCAT_HOME** = C:\Tomcat7

```
C:\Tomcat7\webapps\DBConnection\WEB_INF\classes\DBConnection>javac -cp .,C:\Tomc
at7\lib\servlet-api.jar DBConnnection.java
DBConnnection.java:4: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
DBConnnection.java:5: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.*;
^
DBConnnection.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol: class HttpServlet
public class DBConnnection extends HttpServlet
                                   ^
DBConnnection.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class DBConnection.DBConnnection
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) th
rows ServletException, IOException
                    ^
DBConnnection.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class DBConnection.DBConnnection
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) th
rows ServletException, IOException
                                                ^
DBConnnection.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class DBConnection.DBConnnection
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) th
rows ServletException, IOException

     ^
DBConnnection.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class EmployeeInformation
location: class DBConnection.DBConnnection
                    EmployeeInformation empInfo = new EmployeeInformation();
                    ^
DBConnnection.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class EmployeeInformation
location: class DBConnection.DBConnnection
                    EmployeeInformation empInfo = new EmployeeInformation();
                                                      ^
DBConnnection.java:13: method does not override or implement a method from a sup
ertype
  @Override
  ^
9 errors
```

Im really baffled as to how to proceed! Been stuck at this point!!

Comment: run echo %CLASSPATH% and check is there your classpath look OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `;` to separate classpath entries in Windows

`javac -cp .;C:\Tomcat7\lib\servlet-api.jar DBConnnection.java`.

but, you used a comma `,`. Change comma to semicolon

Note : *nix family environments use colon `:` to seperate classpath entries

Comment: Worked perfectly. Feel so silly for overlooking that!

Comment: Glad, it worked :) . Please accept the answer to close the question.